# Is there a possibility to wait until a specific class disappeared?

Tags: selenium

I am new to Selenium and facing a problem. I want to wait until the loading screen disappeared in my testapplication. The loadingscreen is not an element but a class which lays on the html element when visible. I saw some similar posts, but they all aim to an element to be disappeared. I just want the class of an element to be invisible.

Loading screen visible:

```
<html class="busy">
 ...
</html>
```

loading screen disappeared:

```
<html>
 ...
</html>
```

My intent was to do it with a WebDriverWait, where I used Expected Conditions. But with my solution right now I saw that I would be waiting for the html element to disappear and not the class.

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("busy")));
```

I want to find out if and how it is possible to wait until just the class disappeared and if this is even possible with the webdriver wait.until function

Comment: Class is also an html element i.e. a css class which adds styling to html element.

Comment: Think about the problem slightly differently...you're really wanting to wait for the html element's "class" attribute to change from "busy" to something else.  Search for keywords "webdriverwait expectedconditions attribute" and you'll have a variety of solutions.

Comment: What happened when you ran your code? That should work unless there are other elements that contain that class.

Answer (score 0):

Early in my QA career I encountered a situation where such overlay blockers were implemented.  Below was my solution, you should be able to modify it to suit your needs.

```
public static void waitForBlockUIToDisappear() {
    // This function checks the entire currently-loaded web page for the
    // presence of any web element of the
    // class "blockUI" and loops until there are none. The presence of an
    // element with this class does exactly
    // what it implies: it blocks user input. If you get the error that a
    // different web element would receive
    // the click, for example, this is why and you'd need to call this
    // method before doing a click. Generally,
    // this function should be implemented before sending any input to a web
    // page - click, sendkeys, select...
    String blockUI = "//*[contains(@class,'blockUI')]";
    while (true) {
        if (driver.findElements(By.xpath(blockUI)).size() == 0)
            break;
    }
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, they helped finding my solution. I found out that in this application exist two loading screens. A first one which only appears when starting the application and a second one when the html element is changed with the class.

This first loading screen is an html element. So what I am doing is simply to wait until this is invisible:

```
    WebElement initScreen = driver.findElement(By.className("loading-screen"));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(initScreen));
```

and the second one is the one I mentioned in my question there I was able to use the attribute function:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(By.xpath("/html"), "cursor", "auto"));
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: (the loading screens always look the same and I don't have access to the code, hence I thought they were the same - meanwhile I found out that they aren't the same)